# Cython: assignment operator for stack allocated object causing segfault

Tags: python, c++, cython

I am new to Cython but am very interested in the smooth interface between C/C++ and Python which it promises.  I have hit an issue which I cannot work through on my own.

**Executive summary**

When I try to assign a stack-allocated C++ object wrapped in Cython with the value of another one, I get a segfault.  I cannot understand why this is occurring.

**Details**

I am working with a code base with a class to read and write a custom format for a binary serialization of some data.  Below is a minimal reimplementation of the C++ code reading from the binary.  The `Datastore` class is the main interface into the binary data files.  It uses a generator-like object, implemented as a subclass `Datastore<T>::generator`, to read through the files holding the binary data until the file is exhausted.  Individual records are typed as an inner class, `Datastore<T>::record`.

```
// datastore.hpp:  a minimal implementation of the custom binary reader

#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>

template <typename T>
class Datastore
{

public:
    class generator;
    class record;
    class end_of_datastore_error;

    Datastore(
        std::string  _datastoreFileName
    ):
        datastoreFileName(_datastoreFileName)
    {
    }

    typename Datastore<T>::generator begin()
    {
        return generator(datastoreFileName, false);
    }

    typename Datastore<T>::generator end()
    {
        return generator(datastoreFileName, true);
    }

private:
    std::string  datastoreFileName;
};


template <typename T>
class Datastore<T>::record
{
public:
    record():
        data("")
    {
    }

    record(
        const std::string& _data
    ):
        data(_data)
    {
    }

    ~record() { }

    std::string getData() const { return data; }

private:
    std::string  data;
};


template <typename T>
class Datastore<T>::generator
{
public:
    generator():
        datastoreFileName(""),
        currentRecord(record()),
        done(false),
        data_stream(std::unique_ptr<std::ifstream>(nullptr))
    {
    }

    generator(std::string _datastoreFileName,
              bool        _done);

    ~generator() { if (data_stream->is_open()) data_stream->close(); }

    generator(const generator& rhs) = delete;
    generator& operator=(const generator& rhs) = delete;

    generator(generator&& rhs) = default;
    generator& operator=(generator&& rhs) = default;

    void next();

    bool operator==(const generator& rhs) {
      // equality holds if both generators are not done and point to the same record
      // or if they are both done
      return ((not done and not rhs.done
               and &currentRecord == &rhs.currentRecord)
              or (done and rhs.done));
    }

    bool operator!=(const generator& rhs) {
      return not ((not done and not rhs.done
                   and &currentRecord == &rhs.currentRecord)
                  or (done and rhs.done));
    }

    generator&& operator++();

    Datastore<T>::record& operator*() { return currentRecord; }

    Datastore<T>::record* operator->() { return &currentRecord; }

    std::string             datastoreFileName;
    Datastore<T>::record    currentRecord;
    bool                    done;

private:
    std::unique_ptr<std::ifstream>  data_stream;
};


template <typename T>
class Datastore<T>::end_of_datastore_error:
  virtual public std::ifstream::failure
{
public:
  end_of_datastore_error(const std::string& _msg):
    std::ifstream::failure(_msg)
  {}
};

//------------------------  Implementation  ----------------------------------

template <typename T>
Datastore<T>::generator::generator(
    std::string  _datastoreFileName,
    bool         _done
):
    datastoreFileName(_datastoreFileName),
    currentRecord(Datastore<T>::record()),
    done(_done),
    data_stream(std::unique_ptr<std::ifstream>(
            new std::ifstream(datastoreFileName,
                  std::ios::in | std::ios::binary)))
{
    data_stream->exceptions(
        std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit | std::ios::eofbit);

    next();
}

template <typename T>
typename Datastore<T>::generator&& Datastore<T>::generator::operator++()
{
    try
    {
        next();
    }
    catch (Datastore<T>::end_of_datastore_error& e)
    {
    }

    return std::move(*this);
}

template <typename T>
void Datastore<T>::generator::next()
{
    try
    {
      std::string line;
      std::getline(*data_stream, line);
      currentRecord = record(line);
    }
    catch (std::ifstream::failure e)
    {
        if (data_stream->eof())
        {
            done = true;  // flag used to compare to Datastore<T>::end()
            throw Datastore<T>::end_of_datastore_error("Done reading datastore");
        }
        else
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to expose this library (written in C++) to some folks who primarily use Python.  It seems natural to make use of a generator construct in Python too, so that one could use the following interface in Python:

```
In [1]: from datastore import Datastore as D                                   
In [2]: d = D("example_data/data.dat")                                         
In [3]: for x in d.iteritems():
            some_func(x)  # for example
```

In my implementation of the iteritems method (see below), everything is working fine except when I try to assign a value to a stack-allocated variable of the generator type.  Here are my Cython description and implementation files.

```
#cdatastore.pxd
from libcpp.string cimport string

cdef extern from "cpp/datastore.hpp":
    cdef cppclass Datastore[T]:
        cppclass record:
            record()
            string getData()
        cppclass generator:
            generator()
            generator(generator&&)
            generator& operator=(generator&&)
            Datastore[T].record& operator*()
            generator&& operator++()

        Datastore(string)
        generator begin()
        generator end()


######################################
#datastore.pyx
cimport cdatastore

from cython.operator cimport dereference as deref
from cython.operator cimport preincrement as inc

cdef class Datastore:
    cdef cdatastore.Datastore[int]* _c_datastore
    cdef cppclass generator
    cdef cppclass record

    def __cinit__(self, data_filename):
        self._c_datastore = new cdatastore.Datastore[int](data_filename)
        if self._c_datastore is NULL:
            raise MemoryError()

    def __dealloc__(self):
       if self._c_datastore is not NULL:
           del self._c_datastore

    def iteritems(self):
        print deref(self._c_datastore.begin()).getData()
        print deref(inc(self._c_datastore.begin())).getData()

        # to show
        print "a"
        cdef cdatastore.Datastore[int].generator g
        print "b"
        print deref(g).getData()
        print "c"
        self._c_datastore.begin()
        print "d"
        deref(self._c_datastore.begin())
        print "e"
        g = self._c_datastore.begin()
        print "f"
```

Using a dummy file, with contents "data line 1\ndata line2 (etc)", what I really see is this:

```
In [1]: from datastore import Datastore as D                                   
In [2]: d = D("example_data/data.dat")                                         
In [3]: d.iteritems()
data line 1
data line 2
a
b

c
d
e
Segmentation fault: 11 (core dumped)
```

The problem line is `g = self._c_datastore.begin()`, which I think means my problem comes from my wrapper on the `generator& operator=(generator&&)` but I cannot unpack the exact cause and find a solution.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's the line in `~generator()`:

```
{ if (data_stream->is_open()) data_stream->close(); }
```

You're calling functions on a null pointer (because you initialised `data_stream` to `nullptr` in the `generator()` constructor).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  This did prove to be the cause of my issue.  To add a bit of detail, Cython can only instantiate a stack allocated object of user-defined C++ class type by calling its null (parameter-free) constructor.  And after initializing the object the holding my generator using the move assignment operator to give it a new value called the destructor of the first object.